# jquery chained ajax with looping multiple dependency

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to chain 3 ajax calls and each of these returns an array that is needed by the next call. Here is my code:

```
function getCompanies(){
   return $.ajax({
    url :'.../GetCompanies'
   });
}

 function getDepartments(companyid){
   return $.ajax({
    url :'.../GetDepartments/companyid'
   });
}

 function getEmployees(deptid){
   return $.ajax({
    url :'.../GetEmployees/deptid'
   });
}

function GetAll(){
 $.when(getCompanies()).done(function(data){                            
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
            console.log(value.name); //company name 
        $.when(getDepartments(value.id)).done(function(data){
           $.each(data, function(index, value){     
                console.log(value.name); //department name                              
                $.when(getEmployees(value.id)).done(function(data){ 
                    $.each(data, function(index, value){                                    
                    console.log(value.name); //employee name
                    });                                             
                .......
```

My problem is that the output is like this:

```
     Company 1 
     Company 2
     Company 3
     Dept 1 ( of company 1)
     Employee 1
     Employee 2 
     Dept 2 ( of company 1)
     ....
```

I need it to be:

```
    Company1
    Dept 1 ( of company 1)
    Employee 1
    Dept 2 ( of company 1)

    Company 2
    Dept 1 ( of company 2)
```

Also I need to call all 3 apis, there is no other way around this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The use of `$.when()` is unnecessary in this case as each method returns a single promise.  Just attach the next method to the previous promise with a `.then()`

Comment: Hi, but I need the output of the first when for the next call, how do I do this using then after the for loop? Can you provide a code sample? Sorry I am a total noob at this.

Comment: Like I said, `$.when(promise).done()` is the same as `promise.done()`.  The only time when behaves differently is if you have multiple promises, ex `$.when(promise, promise)` in which case the when will only resolve when all the promises you have given to it have resolved.

Comment: If you want the processing of company 2 to not happen until company 1 is done, you can't use a $.each.  All your ajax calls are non-blocking, which is the way they should be.  If you want company 2 to not start until after company 1, you will need to make the start of company 2 be a done() or then() off of a promise that is processing company 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this would work.

```js
function getCompanies() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '.../GetCompanies'
  });
}

function getDepartments(companyid) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '.../GetDepartments/companyid'
  });
}

function getEmployees(deptid) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '.../GetEmployees/deptid'
  });
}

function GetAll() {
  function processCompanies(companies) {
    if (companies.length) {
      var company = shift(companies); //pop the first company off the array

      console.log(company.name);

      //get the departments for the company and process them
      getDepartments(company.id).then(function(departments) {
        processDepartments(companies, departments);
      });
    }
  }

  function processDepartments(companies, departments) {
    if (departments.length) {
      var department = shift(departments); //pop the first department off the array

      console.log(department.name);

      //get the employees for the department and process themm
      getEmployees(department.id).then(function(employees) {
        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
          console.log(employee.name);
        });
        
        //we have now processed all the employees for this department
        //process the next department
        processDepartments(companies, departments);
      });
    } else {
     //there are no more departments in this company
      //process the next company
      processCompanies(companies);
    }
  }

  getCompanies().then(processCompanies);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much flatter example of what you are trying to do.

It is based on a [live API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) that stores Users, dummy blog posts and comments for those posts.

Following gets a collection of users, then gets all the posts for each specific user and then gets all the comments for each specific post

End result is all the requests have been completed at the end and the final user collection inside `getUsers()` callback has all the posts and comments nested into each user

It should be fairly easy to translate the various methods to match yours since the nesting level is the same

```js
var baseUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`

function getUsers() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + 'users?_limit=3'
  }).then(function(users) {
    //returns promise of getting all posts for all users
    // all the posts also return promises below to get comments for each post
    return getAllPosts(users).then(function() {
      return users // return the users when all the other promises have resolved
    });
  })
}
// makes request for posts for an individual user
function getUserPosts(user) {
  var url = baseUrl + `posts?_limit=3&userId=${user.id}`
  return $.ajax({
    url: url
  }).then(function(posts) {
     // assign posts to current user
     user.posts = posts;
     return posts;
     // returns promise to get comments for these posts
  }).then(getAllPostsComments)
}
// makes request for comments for an individual post
function getPostComments(post) {
  var url = baseUrl + `comments?_limit=3&postId=${post.id}`
  return $.ajax({
    url: url
  }).then(function(comments) {
    post.comments = comments// assign comments array to the specific post
  });
}
// creates promise array for all users posts requests
function getAllPosts(allUsers) {
  var postPromises = allUsers.map(getUserPosts)
  return Promise.all(postPromises)
}
// creates promise array for specific user's posts comments
function getAllPostsComments(userPostsArray) {
  var postPromises = userPostsArray.map(getPostComments);
  return Promise.all(postPromises)
}

// now get all the data
getUsers().then(function(users) {
  // all the posts and post comments are nested in each user object here
  console.log(users)
  

}).catch(err=>console.log('error occured in promise chain', err))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```